# Parse DB/Mongo compound index with an OR and an Object

Tags: mongodb, indexing, parse-platform, compound-index

I am working on a project where the data is stored in a very weird shape that's causing the query for finding an user on first login attempt to TAKE A LONG TIME. I'm having a hard time wrapping my mind around how I can create an index for this. I want to find a single user. Any of these attributes can undefined, and I need to find a single user that match any of these (OR)

```
query.equalTo('firebaseUid', uid);
query.equalTo('emails.apple', email);
query.equalTo('emails.google', email);
query.equalTo('phoneNumber', phoneNumber);
query.equalTo('emails.facebook', email);
query.equalTo('emails.password', email);
```

Is this index correct or makes sense? I'm specifically lost on the fact that we are using `find` within an emails Object (Don't ask me why we are keeping them  separate...). It's most likely an user has an UID than not (After first login). And from there I ordered from most likely login method based on user status (Mostly apple users, then google...)

```
db.userCollection.createIndex({firebaseUid: 1, emails.apple: 1, emails.google: 1, phoneNumber: 1, emails.facebook: 1, emails.password: 1})
```

Comment: I'd create a separate index for each of the fields.

Comment: Can you create an index for an attribute of an Object? So `emails.apple`, 'e-mails.google' and so on? And if I create a separate index, does it mean I need to do separate queries?

Comment: yes. you can create an index for 'emails.facebook'. You told that you are doing an or query. So I imagine you are actually doing something like this: `Parse.Query.or(query1, query2, query3)`. If that's the case, I'd go with one index for each of the constraints.

Comment: I was calling the queries separately and then grabbing the first result (Inside of a Promise.all). You think using an `or` like that once I index each of them individually will help?

Comment: indexing them individually will help in both cases: either using OR or running the queries separately. I'd use the OR though.